# System.IO.FileNotFound when passing file path value to OpenXML GetCellValue()

Tags: c#, openxml, filepicker

When I pass the value from the OpenFilePicker() method back to the button click method, I can utilize a debug string and ensure that the value is not null.

However, when I pass it to the GetCellValue() method, a 'FileNotFound' exception is thrown. Utilizing a debug statement here also shows that the value is not null and returns a valid file path of "C:\Test.xlsx".

Tried changing file permissions to RWX for all, attempted different folder locations. All permissions and folders seem to have the same issue.

```cs
   public async void FileSelectButton_ClickAsync(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            string filePath = await openFilePicker();
            //Debug.WriteLine("result:: " + filePath);
            GetCellValue(filePath, "Sheet1", "A1");
        }

        public async Task<string> openFilePicker()
        {
            var archerReportPicker = new 
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.FileOpenPicker(); 
            archerReportPicker.ViewMode = 
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerViewMode.Thumbnail; 
            archerReportPicker.SuggestedStartLocation = 
            Windows.Storage.Pickers.PickerLocationId.Downloads; 
            archerReportPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xlsx");
            archerReportPicker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".xls"); // Default extensions
            Windows.Storage.StorageFile archerReport = await archerReportPicker.PickSingleFileAsync(); //Get file
            if (archerReport != null)
            {
                // Application now has read/write access to the picked file
                this.fileTextBox.Text = archerReport.Name; // Load it up and throw the data in the textbox.
                var filePath = archerReport.Path;
                return filePath;
            }
            else
            {
                this.fileTextBox.Text = "";
                return null;
            }
        }

        public static string GetCellValue(string fileName, string sheetName, string addressName)
        {

            string value = null;

            // Open the spreadsheet document for read-only access.
            using (SpreadsheetDocument document = SpreadsheetDocument.Open(fileName, false)) //Line where exception is thrown
            {...}
```

Throws System.IO.FileNotFound Exception as opposed to opening valid file path.

The issue also occurs when filePath or fileName is defined using `const string '@c:\test.xlsx'`

Comment: Prior to the `using` statement where the exception occurs, what is the literal value of `fileName`?  Can you debug and show us the actual variable contents?

Comment: Sure. adding the code ```Debug.Writeline("result:: " + fileName)``` results in the _result:: C:\Test.xlsx_ being written to the debug console.

Comment: Since openFilePicker returns Task<string> you could call .Result like this: string filePath = await openFilePicker().Result; Keep in mind this will block the current thread.

Comment: @JakeSteffen, this causes an entirely different issue, stating that ```string does not contain a definition for GetAwaiter```.

Comment: I think I saw that recently. Try putting the await openFilePicker() in its own variable before calling .Result on it like this: var tmpResult = await openFilePicker(); Also what version of .Net is the project targeting?

Comment: @JakeSteffen Utilizing this simply changes the error above thrown to a the new line where I call result on the temporary variable. I believe the error has to do with the return type of ``public async Task<string> openFilePicker()```, not necessarily the typing of the variable. I'm unsure on .NET version, since it's a UWP app targeting 1809/1903, but I would assume 4.5. This information is not given in the normal place for UWP applications.

Comment: Can you remove the async keyword from openFilePicker? I noticed that GetCellValue is not async.

Comment: @JakeSteffen, I cannot because to my knowledge that would require me to use ```PickSingleFileAndContinue()``` which is obsolete, and cannot be used, according to VS2019.

Comment: It may be of note that even if I statically define the path with ```const string filePath = @"c:\test.xlsx"```, it throws the same exception.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer to this question is here:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/wsdevsol/2012/12/04/skip-the-path-stick-to-the-storagefile/

The gist of it is that in UWP, Storage Pickers return a non-filesystem bound  Windows.Storage object. You can glean the filesystem path *from the object*, but because you are performing an operation on a *secondary object*, the fact that the user gave permissions for the first object does not apply to the second, resulting in an Access Denied condition when attempting to open the file - even if NTFS permissions allow 'Everyone' access.

This can be confirmed by monitoring the application using Process Monitor from SystemInternals.

If I discover a work-around to this issue, I will update this answer, but I will likely move away from UWP back towards a Windows Forms Application to avoid this issue entirely.